# Difference in OnClick for ImageButton inside a GridView vs. regular ImageButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, imagebutton

I'm working on a ASP.NET/C# project, and have a GridView control. One of the columns is a TemplateField/ItemTemplate with an ImageButton inside. During the OnClick event, I make a panel visible. When doing this with a regular ImageButton, the page reloads and the panel is visible. This doesn't happen with my ImageButton inside of the GridView. Does anyone know how I can make it do so, or why this is the case?

Thanks for your time, please let me know if you have any questions.

Here's the relevant asp definition

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="90px"  ItemStyle-VerticalAlign ="Bottom" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center" HeaderText="Add Alias">
                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="11px" VerticalAlign="Bottom"/>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID ="btnAddAliasHeader" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/AddAlias.gif" onclick="btnAddAlias_Click" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

And here's the C# for the OnClick function.

```
protected void btnAddAlias_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton btnAddAlias = (ImageButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btnAddAlias.Parent.Parent;
    int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;

    lblSelectedCity.Text = gvResults.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
    lblSelectedCountry.Text = ddlCountry.Text;
    pnlAddAlias.Visible = true;

}
```

I added the OnRowCommand event and made the panel visible there, however it still doesn't show up. I think it may have something to do with postback, because if I then click the button outside of the gridview, on the reload then the panel from the button inside the gridview shows up fine.

Edit: I'm an idiot and left out that all of this is happening in an updatepanel.

Comment: Are both the `GridView` and the `Panel` inside the same `UpdatePanel`?

Answer (score 2):

`Button`s, `ImageButton`s and `LinkButton`s do not fire `Click` events when they are in a control template like you describe.  (Edit: unless used with the `OnClick` property of the control) Instead, the containing control fires an event, in the case of the `GridView` it is a `RowCommand` event.  Use the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` properties of your button to determine the proper action to take in the event handler as shown below:

Markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="DoStuff" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RecordID") %>' Text="DoStuff"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Code:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "DoStuff" Then
        'Do something with e.CommandArgument'
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: They do fire their events however, I can walk through the debugger to where they happen. Is the way the postback works different for an ImageButton inside a Gridview?

Answer (score 0):

The buttons/imagebuttons inside a container such as a gridview (listview, repeater, etc) have their click event bubbled up to the container itself. To make the panel visible, you need to use the command name and command argument properties on the button, and then use the OnRowCommand event of the gridview to dispay the panel

HTH

Comment: I added the OnRowCommand event and made the panel visible there, however it still doesn't show up. I think it may have something to do with postback, because if I then click the button outside of the gridview, on the reload then the panel from the button inside the gridview shows up fine.

Comment: @Nick: As pseudocoder mentioned in their comment on the original question, are both the gridview and the panel in the same update panel? if not, then you'll have to add a trigger to the update panel that contains the panel you wish to show.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing your event isn't firing - you should use the commandname attribute on the imagebutton - and pick it up on the onrowcommand of the gridview - or register your imagebutton click event in the onrowcreated event.

Answer (score 0):

If the postback is not needed.  Sorry if I misunderstood the question.  You could instead of using an image button (server control), use a link or regular image wrapped in an a tag and jQuery.  This will prevent the postback to the server.  Hope this helps.

```
<a href="#" id="viewPanel">Click to View Panel</a>
```

---

```
$("#<%=viewPanel.ClientID%>").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#id_of_panel").show();

});
```

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: He wasn't asking to avoid a postback or run client side code...?

Comment: @pseudocoder - He added code after I read the question.  Also he said he wanted to make a panel visible.  I was giving him an alternative if no processing at the server was needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can user Oncommand Event for gridview rather than using Onclick on the perticular control only you have to pass commandname from the control and check it by e.commandname and do what ever you want to perform